# onclick com .append enviando função com variável

Tags: javascript

Primeiramente meu codigo:

```
function renderLiberarCarro(liberar, userId, docId){
  var documentId =  docId;
  var aviso = '<span class="badge badge-pill badge-sussess">Liberar</span>';
  var photo = '<%= dataUser.photo %>';
  if(photo == null){
      photo =  "public/assets/images/users/avatar-2.jpg";
  }
$("table.liberar tbody").append(
    '<tr class='+documentId+'>'+

        '<td class='+liberar.marca+'> Cliente Medcar: '+ liberar.cliente +'</td>'+
        '<td class='+liberar.marca+'>'+ liberar.marca +'</td>'+
        '<td class='+liberar.marca+'>'+ liberar.modelo +'</td>'+
        '<td class='+liberar.marca+'>'+ liberar.ano +'</td>'+
        '<td class='+liberar.marca+'>'+ aviso +'</td>'+
        '<td class='+liberar.marca+'><a onclick=\"liberarCarro('+documentId+')\" id="'+ docId +'" href="#" data="'+docId+'" class="btn btn-secondary action-liberar btn-sm waves-effect">Liberar</a> '+
    '</tr>'
    );

};
function liberarCarro(docId){
    console.log(docId)
}
```

no ultimo td insiro um a onclick nele e chamo a função liberar carro e passo um valor, mas em vez de vir o valor o retorno está sendo este:

```
<a onclick="liberarCarro(eVzsQHCk4UozJ4MQI26S)" id="eVzsQHCk4UozJ4MQI26S" href="#" data="eVzsQHCk4UozJ4MQI26S" class="btn btn-secondary action-liberar btn-sm waves-effect">Liberar</a>
```

está retornand a tag a completa, oq eu esperava de retorno era apenas: eVzsQHCk4UozJ4MQI26S. Alguem sabe me dizer o porque?

Obrigado

Comment: RESOLVIDO:         '<td class='+liberar.marca+'><a onclick="liberarCarro("'+documentId+'")" id="'+ docId +'" href="#" data="'+docId+'" class="btn btn-secondary action-liberar btn-sm waves-effect">Liberar</a> '+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acontece que você está passando para a função uma string de texto sem aspas:

```
onclick="liberarCarro(eVzsQHCk4UozJ4MQI26S)"
                                ↑
                     sem aspas delimitadoras
```

Desta forma, o que é enviado para a função como parâmetro é o próprio elemento que chamou o `onclick`.

Se o parâmetro fosse um valor numérico, aí sim a função receberia esse valor. Por exemplo:

```
onclick="liberarCarro(103)"
                       ↑
                     número
```

O `console.log(docId)` exibiria `103`.

Neste caso, se não quer enviar o próprio elemento para a função, é preciso sempre delimitar o argumento com aspas simples ou duplas (no seu caso, seriam aspas simples escapadas porque o `onclick` usa aspas duplas e a concatenação é feita com aspas simples).

Ficaria assim (não há necessidade de escapar as aspas duplas do `onclick` como vem fazendo):

```
onclick="liberarCarro(\''+documentId+'\')"
                       ↑               ↑
                    aspas simples escapadas
```